# localId when uploading an existing user with gitkitclient

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

1. Are there any constraints on the localId when uploading a user? Can it be a uuid with inserted hyphen characters ?
2. Is it bad practice to use increasing numbers for the localId?
3. When uploading a GitkitUser I tried not setting the localId but got an exception. Is there a way to create a new user without providing a localId and let identity toolkit generate and return the localId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No constraints on the localId. Uuid with hyphen is fine.
2. It is -not- recommended to use guessable value for localId.
3. LocalId is required in the upload request because once Identity Toolkit authenticates the user, your server will receive the IdToken, extract the localId in the token, and looks up the user data in your database using the localId as the key.